# Kafka session time out issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to kafka, I try to consume data from kafka using python which take 10 min to process one message from kafka consumer queue. I found that same message is looped and received again and again. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic_name,
                         bootstrap_servers=['localhost'],auto_offset_reset='earliest',enable_auto_commit=True,group_id="tangoit",max_poll_records=1,session_timeout_ms=700000,request_timeout_ms=800000,heartbeat_interval_ms=233334)                      
count =1
while True:
    msg_pack = consumer.poll(max_records=1)
    for tp, messages in msg_pack.items():
        for message in messages:
            time.sleep(600) // instead of sleep message processing will happend and it take 10 min to process that message
```

Comment: Can you share the full code?

Comment: I share full code. Using python I try to achieve this

Comment: Are you using `confluent-python` or `kafka-python`?

Comment: I'm using kafka python

Comment: you have to commit the offset before the timeout or the record will result as not read. `auto.commit.interval.ms` for autocommit defaults to 5000. Since you have `auto_offset_reset='earliest'` everytime you start the application it will read all the messages present